# Filtering by value in Redis (using go and redis-go)

Tags: go, redis

I'm using this function to get orders by status, the problem with this function is that the filtering happens after I get all my orders from redis is there a way to filter by value redis-side like in Postgres (a where statement for example) or does redis not support that?

```golang
func (r *queryResolver) OrdersByStatus(ctx context.Context, status string) ([]*models.Order, error) {
    defer utils.Elapsed("redis query => orders")()

    myCtx := ctx.Value(constants.KMyContext).(types.MyCtx)

    sessionData, sessionErr := session.GetSessionData(myCtx.ResponseWriter, myCtx.Request, constants.KCurrentUser)

    if sessionErr != nil {
        return nil, sessionErr
    }

    marshalledStories, err := cache.RedisClient.Get(ctx, constants.KOrders+sessionData.UUID).Result()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("redis get err", err)
        return nil, errors.New(constants.InternalServerError)
    }
    var orders []*models.Order

    unmarshallErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(marshalledStories), &orders)

    if unmarshallErr != nil {
        log.Println("redis unmarshallErr", unmarshallErr)
        return nil, errors.New(constants.InternalServerError)
    }

    var filtered []*models.Order

    for _, u := range orders {
        if u.Status == status {
            filtered = append(filtered, u)
        }
    }

    return filtered, nil
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running a custom command with the MATCH statement? https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#example-package-CustomCommand I think in general this isn't the use-case for Redis though

Comment: No, I haven't tried MATCH statements can you show me an example

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this will only work on the keys, you can't filter by value on the Redis-side. This should still be very fast though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use https://github.com/tidwall/gjson to query the marshalledStories

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could get since you are storing a serialized JSON array at a single key is to run a Lua script using `EVAL` that parses the JSON stored at the key, filters the entries based on the `status` value, and then re-serializes and saves the results either at the same key or a different key. This would be faster in that it would be executed entirely on the Redis server, but it is also harder to debug / more error-prone.

You can use `cjson.decode` to parse JSON and `cjson.encode` to re-serialize it.

Something like this:

```
local myKey = KEYS[1]
local status = ARGV[1]

local raw = redis.call("GET", myKey)
local orders = cjson.decode(raw)
local filteredOrders = {}
local index = 1

for order, _ in ipairs(orders) do
  if order["status"] == status then
    filteredOrders[index] = order
    index = index + 1
  end
end

local resultRaw = cjson.encode(filteredOrders)
redis.call("SET", myKey, resultRaw)
```